# php in_array is not comparing existing value

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array1 ( [0] => 21 ) 
Array2 ( [0] => 22 [1] => 22,20,21 [2] => 16 )
```

no match found

how to compare:-
`[0]=>21` 
in array2, there is 21 in array2 but it displays match not found message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array( '21' );
$array2 = array( '22','22,20,21','16');

foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($array2 as $key2=>$value2){
        $temp = explode(',', $value2);
        if(in_array($value, $temp)){
             echo $value.' exist in both arrays at Index '.$key2.' of Array2 and '.$key.' of Array1';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

> hey @babul shrestha you can do it like :

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(0 => 21);
$arr2 = array(0 => 22, 1 => "22,20,21", 2 => 16);
$newarr2Str = "";
foreach($arr2 as $val){
    $newarr2Str .= $val.",";
}
var_dump(in_array("21", array_values(array_filter(explode(',', $newarr2Str))))); // it will give true
```

Comment: @babul shrestha try this updated one

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
   $a= array('0'=>21,'1'=>22,'2'=>23,'3'=>24,'4'=>25);
   $b=array('0'=>23,'1'=>21);
   foreach($b as $c){
    if(in_array($c,$a)){
     echo $c;
      }
   }

  ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help ,but that is not what i mean

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.